# Using onEdit() with a spreadsheet that check for information from another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying to debug this code for a few hours now with no luck. I have a script (code below) tied to a google sheet called "EDIT". I am trying to make it so that when someone enters a person's name in a section of the "EDIT" sheet, the script will automatically refer (via an onEdit trigger) to a contact info spreadsheet I have (separate spreadsheet), find the row with the person's name, and then copy their email address from that row and paste it into my "EDIT" spreadsheet next to the person's name. I keep running into issues with calling another spreadsheet though. Any advice?

Code:

```
function onEdit(e){
//making sure the edited range is from the correct sheet
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == "EDIT"){
    var eRange = e.range;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EDIT");
    var contactSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1IooSZ8jclhwWTZDKc_h_o4wpQoMyuDHVT5q8CqAbT7M").getSheetByName("2024");
    
    //iterating through each cell of the edited range (for each new name)
    for (var n=1;n<=eRange.getNumRows();n++){
      var cell = eRange.getCell(n,1)
      //making sure cell of editted range is withing range of interest
      if(cell.getA1Notation() == "J25"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J26"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J27"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J28"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J29"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J30"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J31"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J32"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J33"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J34"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J35"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J36"||cell.getA1Notation() == "J37"){
      //making sure cell has name, wasn't just edited to be blank (deleted text)
      if(cell.getValue() !== ""){
          var nameToFind = cell.getValue();
          var firstAndLastNames = contactSheet.getRange(2,3,contactSheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
          var fullNames = [];
          for (i = 0;i<firstAndLastNames.length;i++){
              fullNames[i] = (firstAndLastNames[i][0] + " " + firstAndLastNames[i][1])
              if (fullNames[i] == nameToFind){
                var email = contactSheet.getRange(i+2,10).getValue();
                ss.getRange(eRange.getRow(),13).setValue(email);
              }
              SpreadsheetApp.flush()
          }
      }
    }}
  }
}
```

Comment: Using SpreadsheetApp.flush in a loop like that is going to make the code run extremely slow and the handler function for a simple onEdit trigger terminates at 30 seconds.  I would try to just put all of of the name data into an object and store the object in properties service and extract it every time parse and use it.  I would need to now how the contact information is store and what the input names look like.  I'd  rather just rewrite it than debug your code.

Comment: input names are just full names (ex. John Smith), the contact form has a lot of rows and 4 columns (first name, last name, email, cell)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the rep to comment, but first thing to note is that sharing the specific error message you are getting would be helpful.  Having said that, I've suggested a few changes to your code below (including putting the call to the external sheet in a try/catch block to make sure you capture any errors there)

```
function updateOnEdit(e){
//Set this up to run as an installable trigger
//https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
//making sure the edited range is from the correct sheet
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == "EDIT"){
    var eRange = e.range;
    var eValues = e.range.getValues();//we'll use this later to update the spreadsheet in one go...
    var updatedValues = false //changes to true below, if a change is made...

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EDIT"); //don't think you need this

    //just get the data from the external sheet once, rather than every loop... Also put in a try/catch loop to catch any errors you might be getting here
    try {
      var contactSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1IooSZ8jclhwWTZDKc_h_o4wpQoMyuDHVT5q8CqAbT7M").getSheetByName("2024");
      var firstAndLastNames = contactSheet.getRange(2,3,contactSheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
    } catch(e) {
      Logger.log("Error getting contact sheet: %s", e.message)
      return; //no point continuing if you get an error here
    }    
    
    //iterating through each cell of the edited range (for each new name)
    for (var n=1;n<=eRange.getNumRows();n++){
      var cell = eRange.getCell(n,1)
      const interestRange = ["J25", "J26", "J27", "J28", "J29"]; //you get the gist
      //easier to read if statement follows...
      if (interestRange.includes(cell.getA1Notation())) {
      //making sure cell has name, wasn't just edited to be blank (deleted text)
        if(cell.getValue() !== ""){
          var nameToFind = cell.getValue();
          // moved the line below, to the top of the function above, outside the loop...
          //var firstAndLastNames = contactSheet.getRange(2,3,contactSheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
          var fullNames = [];
          for (i = 0;i<firstAndLastNames.length;i++){
              fullNames[i] = (firstAndLastNames[i][0] + " " + firstAndLastNames[i][1])
              if (fullNames[i] == nameToFind) {
                var email = contactSheet.getRange(i+2,10).getValue();
                // ss.getRange(eRange.getRow(),13).setValue(email)
                //try this instead, using 12 as the values array starts at zero
                eValues[i][12] = email;
                updatedValues = true; //you made a change to the values, so signal it here.
              }
              //don't need this - see below
              //SpreadsheetApp.flush()//
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //Now outside the loop - only need to update the spreadsheet IF values were changed...
    if (updatedValues) {
      try {
        eRange.setValue(eValues) // this will update the entire range.
      } catch(e) {
        Logger.log("Spreadsheet update failed: %s", e.message)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still having a similar issue though, and not getting any error messages. It seems to quit when opening a new spreadsheet. Is this an oath thing or an onEdit thing maybe?

Comment: Have you checked your executions for error messages? Just in case you're not - If you're using scripts.google.com to edit the code, on the left hand side menu bar you'll see one of the menu options is "Executions".  It has the history of functions that have been executed and - especially if you are use the logger.log options - any logs the function outputs.

Comment: Also, when I find I am regularly accessing data in another sheet, rather than do that with code, I just create a separate sheet (hidden if need be) and use the importrange function to pull the data I need into my sheet.

If you were doing this, your code could be trimmed down a little and probably run faster.

I've added an additional answer to show what the code would look like if you went down this track...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use importrange(...) to pull the data into the existing sheet, code could be adjusted as shown below.  Note, I am assuming the sheet you are importing data to is called 'Import_Names'.

```
function addEmailifNamesMAtch(e) {
  //trying to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78228940/using-onedit-with-a-spreadsheet-that-check-for-information-from-another-spread
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == "EDIT"){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var firstAndLastNames = ss.getSheetByName("Import_Names").getDataRange().getValues();

    var eRange = e.range;
    var eValues = e.range.getValues();//we'll use this later to update the spreadsheet in one go...
    var updatedValues = false //changes to true below, if a change is made...

    //iterating through each cell of the edited range (for each new name)
    for (var n=1;n<=eRange.getNumRows();n++){
      var cell = eRange.getCell(n,1)
      const interestRange = ["J25", "J26", "J27", "J28", "J29"]; //you get the gist
      //easier to read if statement follows...
      if (interestRange.includes(cell.getA1Notation())) {
      //making sure cell has name, wasn't just edited to be blank (deleted text)
        if(cell.getValue() !== ""){
          var nameToFind = cell.getValue();
          var fullNames = [];
          for (i = 0;i<firstAndLastNames.length;i++){
            fullNames[i] = (firstAndLastNames[i][0] + " " + firstAndLastNames[i][1])
            if (fullNames[i] == nameToFind) {
              var email = contactSheet.getRange(i+2,10).getValue();
              // ss.getRange(eRange.getRow(),13).setValue(email)
              //try this instead, using 12 as the values array starts at zero
              eValues[i][12] = email;
              updatedValues = true; //you made a change to the values, so signal it here.
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //Now outside the loop - only need to update the spreadsheet IF values were changed...
    if (updatedValues) {
      try {
        eRange.setValue(eValues) // this will update the entire range.
      } catch(e) {
        Logger.log("Spreadsheet update failed: %s", e.message)
      }
    }
  }
}
```